# liquibase is not creating unsigned columns

Tags: mysql, liquibase

My Environment:

- java: 1.8.0_20, 64 bit
- liquibase: 3.3.1
- mysql: 5.5.34
- mysql connector: mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar
- mysql driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
- mysql connection string: jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_db
- mysql user: root user
- os: windows 7 64

database change log xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd">

<changeSet author="jbenton" id="create my_test_tbl table">
   <sql> SET storage_engine=MYISAM; </sql>
    <createTable tableName="my_test_tbl">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="my_test_tbl_id" type="INT UNSIGNED">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column defaultValueNumeric="0" name="col_smallint" type="SMALLINT">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column defaultValueNumeric="0" name="col_smallint_unsigned" type="SMALLINT UNSIGNED"/>
        <column defaultValueNumeric="0" name="col_smallint_unsigned_not_null" type="SMALLINT UNSIGNED">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Using the `updateSql` command, I see the following sql being generated

```
CREATE TABLE my_db.my_test_tbl (
   my_test_tbl_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  col_smallint SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
  col_smallint_unsigned SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NULL, 
  col_smallint_unsigned_not_null SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TEST_TBL PRIMARY KEY (my_test_tbl_id));
```

My goal is that the columns would be `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`.  Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really see what could be wrong here. Looking at the sources I can see a comment `/always smallint regardless of parameters passed` on the [`SmallIntType.java`](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/core/SmallIntType.java) class. I don't oversee the whole code and therefore can't say for sure if this really indicates that further parameters to the type (like "unsigned") are left out. Maybe you can file a bug/enhancement on liquibase-github for this?

Comment: I'll file a bug.  I just wanted to make sure there was nothing obvious that I had missed.  I have seen several examples on stackoverflow where it seems this has worked for others.  Note that the id is an int that I defined as 'int unsigned' and it ends up as a plain old int.

Comment: in version 3.3.2 `type="BIGINT UNSIGNED"` even for that also its created just `BIGINT(20)` not unsigned

Comment: some people are saying UNSIGNED is not an SQL standard. So that liquibase may not be supported that.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented [CORE-2300 Unsigned Int / Bigint cannot be created](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2300) that fixes this issue. It has been merged to the master branch. If you can use a -SNAPSHOT version based on master then you could get the fix before the 3.4.0 release, which I suspect will be in the next few months.

If you're using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Or download it from the build server:

https://liquibase.jira.com/builds/browse/CORE-LB-90/artifact

[liquibase-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip](https://liquibase.jira.com/builds/artifact/CORE-LB/JOB1/build-90/Binary-Packages/liquibase-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip)

Or if you want to use 3.3.x you could create your own 3.3.4-SNAPSHOT

```
$ git clone https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase.git
$ cd liquibase
$ git checkout 3.3.x
$ git cherry-pick 5bf8fc591477587c3f61c876e91011d0b8a6d362
$ git status
$ # resolve the merge conflicts
$ vi liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/core/*IntType.java
$ git add '*.java'
$ git cherry-pick --continue
$ mvn clean verify
```

Then update your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

or use the resultant distribution zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems to be a bug in the current implementation of liquibase, which seems to get fixed with 3.4.0 (cf. https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2300). I tried to implement the commits attached to the issue (https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/5bf8fc591477587c3f61c876e91011d0b8a6d362) on 3.3.2. This resolves the unsigned problem, but creating columns with auto increment of the unsigned types failed.

In the end, I used version 3.0.7, which seems to be last one without this issue. Works flawless so far.